# Why there is no need for a test dataset when using bayesian inference methods?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, overfitting, bayesian-network

In a comment one user said that the true guard against overfitting is the adopted priors but, for example, in bayesian neural networks we still have priors on the weights and the common advice is to use a test dataset to check if there is overfitting